# Is there a way to make a 2 column layout stretch in both directions?

Tags: html, css

I have the following scenario: 
a two column layout made up of divs A and B (in that order) wrapped with a wrapper div centered at the page. I want B to stretch horizontally to `100% - length_of_A` (length of A changes depending on its content), and also for both divs to stretch vertically to fill the height. If A is longer than B then B will stretch, otherwise- A will stretch.

I tried experimenting with width and height and position and overflow values, but couldn't make it work. How do I achieve something like this?

Comment: @EpsilonVector It can be done with JavaScript, of course. But I assume, you want a pure CSS solution, right?

Comment: @Sime Yes this is correct. I'm not familiar enough with Java to just do it, and while I will learn how to if I have to I want to see if a pure CSS solution is possible first.

Comment: @EpsilonVector I'm not sure that I understand your column-width requirements. You want column A to have a variable width depending on its content, and you want column B to also have a variable width depending on the width of column A, right? But how do you want the width of column A to change depending on its content? Do you allow line-wrapping?

Comment: @Sime It can stretch vertically. For the purpose of this questions you can assume that it just stretches vertically with the length of the content and that it will not stretch beyond 50% of the page (because the content will never be that long, not because I expect this to be enforced via CSS).

Comment: @EpsilonVector But based on what criteria does the width of column A change?

Comment: @Sime The longest line in the text. Let's say I have a title and a list of items, and the length of the title is always longer than the length of the list, so the length of the title is what stretches the div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunally there is no cross-browser solution I know to do that using divs, but you could do that using tables like follows:

```
<table style="width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse;"><tr>
    <td id="A"> <h1 style="white-space: nowrap;">...content...</h1> </td>
    <td id="B"> ...content... </td>
</tr></table>
```

You should apply the "white-space: nowrap;" to all those elements that should rule the A column width.
This should do the trick in all common browsers.

Comment: @dubrox The OP wants the width column B to adjust depending on column A. If you set it to a fixed width, then it won't depend...

Comment: @sime vidas You're right, I made the code on the fly and forgot about the detail that the OP wanted both columns to be flexible. Now i fixed my code, tnx :)

Comment: @dubrox Yea, but the width of column A should depend on the length of the title in it, ergo, it should not wrap.

Comment: @sime vidas: I haven't noticed that requirement, but I think that the edit I made (white-space:nowrap) could fit the need.

Comment: id use the NOWRAP attribute instead

Comment: @Knu I'm not sure about it, but I guess "nowrap" HTML attribute is deprecated as the CSS property should be used in its place.

Comment: @dubrox be consistent: ur using table instead of css `display:table`

Comment: @Knu I've used table instead of `display:table` and `display:table-cell` because those properties are not cross-browser (IE6,7 doesn't recognize those CSS properties) and I'm trying to give a cross browser solution.

Answer (score 1):

**Working demo** (uses JavaScript): http://vidasp.net/tinydemos/layout-demo-2.html

However, you cannot set padding to the DIVs that represent the columns.

Also, for some reason setting exact widths doesn't work in IE - that's why I had to leave out 1px on the right.

Comment: On the however note, what @Šime Vidas means is that you should only consider the `div` columns as *column wrappers*, so having another nested *div* with padding is perfectly legal.

Comment: @kRON Yes, the children of the column DIVs may have padding.

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem with my page but with 3 divs. My solutions was to use javascript code to get width and height of the page  **offsetHeight and  offsetWidth**.

For example use code bellow to get half of some element's width.

`var midpoint = document.getElementById("MyElementId").offsetWidth/2;` .

Comment: I assume the script has to run "on load"? If not, then when?

Comment: @EpsilonVector Yes, onload, or even better on DOMReady :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the simplest solution, only the left column may have a bug in IE6 if the content of the right column is longer. And also when the content of the left column is longer than the right column, the text wont fit. But you can fix this with a background image so you wont see that the text doesn't fit the div.

```
<style type="text/css">
* {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
#page {
    background:red;
}
#left {
    width:320px;
    float:left
}
#right {
    background:blue;
    position:relative;
    overflow:hidden
}
</style>
<div id="page">
    <div id="left">
        <ul><li>Lorem ipsum</li><li>Dolor sit amet</li><li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li><li>Lorem ipsum</li><li>Dolor sit amet</li><li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li><li>Lorem ipsum</li><li>Dolor sit amet</li><li>Consectetur adipiscing elit</li></ul>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam laoreet, turpis nec mattis rhoncus, diam arcu dignissim turpis, vel interdum libero mi vitae lorem. Mauris placerat cursus odio at imperdiet. Integer pulvinar ante quis justo mattis mattis. Maecenas interdum mollis lacinia. Cras odio erat, pellentesque eu condimentum ut, ultricies vel neque. Morbi tristique diam elit, eget sagittis est. Nullam vestibulum elit sit amet odio dictum sodales. Duis elementum mollis elementum. Nulla purus elit, suscipit auctor sagittis eget, pretium vitae est. Suspendisse potenti. Integer sit amet ipsum sem. Vestibulum quis auctor leo. Suspendisse at elementum diam.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

(Tested in Safari 5, IE6, IE7 and IE8.)